# How old are the shape of the numbers based on the number of angles?

Tags: notation

There is a famous image that pretends to explain the origin of the shapes of the digits by the number of angles in them.

I do know that it is erroneous but I would like to know if this is an old legend or a recent one. After all, maybe centuries ago, someone spread this false etymology, maybe ten years ago.[image]

Comment: It is not only erroneous, there is not a single digit here which had the same number of lines... except 0.

Comment: Anyways, the form of the digit is coming from the arabs, and they got it from the hindus, as far I know. It has nothing to do with the number of the lines in them, they also looked differently in the ancient Europe, yet more different was the arab version and so on.

Comment: It is not the number of lines, it is the number of angles… But anyway the question is not about the history of the shapes as we usually know them

Comment: My mistake, sorry. But I am not sure how is it science/math history, but it might be accepted as border case (I do not vote it for closure).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the book Florian Cajori "A History of Mathematical Notations" on [pp 65-66](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_History_of_Mathematical_Notations/rhEh8jPGQOcC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA65&printsec=frontcover) says: "A French writer, P. Voizot<a reference to 1899 work>, entertained the theory that originally a numeral contained as many angles as it represents units. ... He did not claim credit for this explanation, but ascribed it to a writer in the Genova Catholico Militarite".